# Button playground swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm just trying to add a button actions which create a view.
Someone can help me?

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        view.addSubview(button)

        class Button: ViewController {
            @objc func fbtn () {
                let newView = UIView()
                newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
                view.addSubview(newView)
            }
        }
        button.addTarget(button, action: #selector(Button.fbtn), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
```

Comment: What's the point of the `Button` class with the `fbtn` function and why is it nested inside `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: `Button` extending `ViewController` inside `ViewController`?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What result are you expecting, and what result are you getting that you don't want?

Comment: I don't know, I'm trying and in this way there are no errors, but it doesn't work... I'm learning to code

Comment: I'm expecting that if I tap on the button, another view appears

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no point to your nested `Button` class. Just make `fbtn` a function of your `ViewController` class. And make `self` the target of the button action.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .black
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
        button.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(button)

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(fbtn), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func fbtn() {
        let newView = UIView()
        newView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        view.addSubview(newView)
    }
}
```

Also, give `newView` a useful frame inside the `fbtn` function.